# Screen resolution in c++ for linux

Tags: c++, height, width, screen

i write a program who would have to interact with the mouse, so I would like to get the screen/monitor widht and height in c++, for linux.
I search on google and here and didn't find anything.
Thank you

Comment: Plain C++ doesn't know about screens or its dimensions, for all C++ knows, the code might run on a screenless system.  Libraries can help you, but you need to specify which library you want to use and whether you are interested in the actual screen, window or canvas size.

Comment: This is for my monitor, in order to interact with my mouse.

Comment: @MelvinFrohike42 we get that, but what we need to know is how is the program run? - is it a console application or does it create a window that the user can interact with? What library are you using to create the window? etc. etc.

Comment: @Baldrickk the programm run on a terminal and i use x11 lib, thank you i'm a bit lost..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use XLibs functions to get the size of a display.

For example, for de default display :

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

Display* d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
Screen*  s = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(d);
```

[XOpenDisplay(NULL)](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/opening.html) to get the main Display of your X server (assuming you have a basic X config with only one display...)

Then get the screen you want the resolution from.
For the main screen, use [DefaultScreenOfDisplay](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/display-macros.html#DefaultScreenOfDisplay), otherwise use : ScreenOfDisplay(display, screen_nb).

Then you get your Screen * structure.

You can access to the height and the width member to get the resolution !

s->height;

s->width;

This is better than using WidthOfScreen/HeightOfScreen because it take only one request to populate the Screen struct. And you probably aldready have it if you are aldready using Xlib in your program and you have the choice of the screen (in case of multiple screen).

You can get the number of screens running on your display by using [ScreenCount(display)](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/display-macros.html#ScreenCount) function

Comment: Code-only answers are not considered high-quality answers at StackOverflow. Please include a description of what your code does and how it solves the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a X environment, you can use the Xlib:
http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/screen-information.html

WidthOfScreen and HeightOfScreen